# How to clone metaplex metadata program to use with solana-test-validator

Tags: metaplex, solana-test-validator

How do you set up `solana-test-validator` with the metaplex metadata program to run tests locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
solana-test-validator --clone-upgradeable-program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s --url https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
```